# Explaination of "warning: assignment from distinct Objective-C type"

Tags: objective-c, string

If I set a mutable string's value to a value from an array, and use the following code to manipulate it:

```
NSMutableString *theCountry = [listItems objectAtIndex:3];
theCountry = [theCountry stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];
```

I receive the warning "warning: assignment from distinct Objective-C type" after the second line of the above code. If I do not have "theCountry =" before the method call, the warning goes away, but the string does not get manipulated...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:` method is declared to return an `NSString*`, not an `NSMutableString*`. Basically, in the assignment, you're assigning an `NSString*` to a variable of type `NSMutableString*` which is not necessarily safe (note that `NSMutableString` inherits `NSString`, not the other way around).

Comment: I'll add that whenever you get this warning it means you are assigning an object of type X into a variable declared for type Y. If you did this intentionally then you should have casted the object, and if you did this unintentionally then you should fix it :-)

Comment: Thanks, I just changed NSMutableString to NSString and it works fine now. No warnings and app still works correctly.